# Behaviour of autoDestroy: false in Extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs4, typeerror, tabpanel

How does autoDestroy:false actually works in Ext-Js 4. 
I am intending to close the tab and then recreate it on click of button, See the code here:

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');

    Ext.onReady(function(){

var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    autoDestroy: false,
    items: [{
        title: 'Home',
        html: 'Home',
        itemId: 'home'

    }, {
        title: 'Tickets',
        html: 'Tickets',
        itemId: 'tickets',
        closable: true,
        closeAction: 'hide'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
    id: 'buttonId',
    text: 'Recreate Tab',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function(){
        var tickets = tabs.child('#tickets');
        tickets.tab.show();

    }
});

  });

</script>
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id="tabs1">
     <div id="script" class="x-hide-display"></div>
     <div id="markup" class="x-hide-display"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tab' of null on click of button. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

After the close, the tickets tab is removed from the tab panel. Thus when you look for it using `tabs.child('#tickets')` you get null back. On the next line you are effectively calling `null.tab` hence the error. You'll need to keep track of the panel before it closes and then use `tabs.add` to bring it back.

Comment: Didn't get what is meant by "You'll need to keep track of the panel before it closes and then use tabs.add to bring it back". Isnt the purpose of autoDestroy: false is to not destroy the instance of tab but just hide it.

Comment: It isn't destroyed, but it is removed from the tab panel. You can try `tabs.child...` right after you `Ext.create` it and then add that variable to tabs in the handler, or just `tabs.add` the config you used to originally create it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to elaborate on how to "keep track of the panel before it closes and then use tabs.add to bring it back."  Please?

Comment: Assign it to a variable using `var tab = tabs.child('#tickets')` or something similar. Then `tabs.add(tab)` to add it back.