# ExtJS Hide tab on close, not delete

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code which creates a tab inside of a tabpanel:

```
id: 'tabs',
region: 'center',
xtype: 'tabpanel',
autoDestroy: false,
items:[{
    xtype: 'country-rate-grid',
    id: 'LegalCompliance',
    title: 'Legal Compliance',
    store: 'RateManagement.store.LegalRateStore',
    hidden: true,
    closable: true,
    listeners: {
        'close': function(tab, eOpts) {
            tab.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

When I close the tab via the X button, and then try to re-open it via `tabs.child('#'+record.data.id).tab.show();`, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tab' of null

It looks like it is deleting the tab instead of hiding it.  How can I just show and hide my tabs instead of deleting them from the DOM when someone clicks the close button on the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Ext JS 4.2.2 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel):

> Note: By default, a tab's close tool destroys the child tab Component and all its descendants. This makes the child tab Component, and all its descendants unusable. To enable re-use of a tab, configure the TabPanel with autoDestroy: false.

**EDIT**: Ok, now I think I get what you're trying to do and where it went wrong. I've looked up the code and it looks like `autoDestroy: false` *does not* in fact destroy a container's child, but it *detaches* that child from the document body and removes it from the container's children collection. That's why you're seeing it disappearing from the DOM. The DOM nodes are not lost however, and are appended to the *detached body* element that is available through `Ext.getDetachedBody()`. That's also why you can't refer to the component by calling `tabs.child(blah)` - the tab has been removed from there.

So if you're trying to kind of hide a tab panel upon closing, to be able to show it again, you'd have to re-insert it back into the tab panel:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        autoDestroy: false,
        items: [{
            id: 'foo',
            title: 'Foo',
            closable: true,
            html: 'foo bar'
        }, {
            id: 'bar',
            title: 'bar',
            closable: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Bring foo back!',
                handler: function() {
                    var foo = Ext.getCmp('foo');

                    foo.ensureAttachedToBody();
                    tabs.insert(foo);
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

`foo.ensureAttachedToBody()` will re-attach the DOM nodes for that panel back to the document body, and then we insert it into the tab panel as if nothing had happened. Voila.

Comment: I added the `autoDestroy: false` to the panel but it still gives me the same error.  I updated the question with my code.  Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Yup; you need to put `autoDestroy: false` on the TabPanel, not its child. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I added it there (and updated the original question with my code) but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: Basically, it's saying that `tabs.child('#'+record.data.id)` is null. The output of `console.log(record.data.id)` is "LegalCompliance" which is the same as my `id: 'LegalCompliance',`

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint there and see what happens. A lot of things could go wrong: record's id could have changed, or something else. Basically, make sure that the tab is actually destroyed and it's not something else.

Comment: It is definitely deleting it.  I have checked the DOM via Chrome's Element tab.  The tab is there, then I click the X and it is removed (which is not what I want).

Comment: Hmm, ok. Which Ext version you're using? I'll look into that; if the tab is being destroyed despite `autoDestroy: false` then it must be a bug.

Comment: I am on version 4.2.1 according to `Ext.getVersion()`

Comment: Hey Alex, I found this link which says that `autoDestroy: false` works differently than expected.  What do you think about this and how can I use this to solve my problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409407/behaviour-of-autodestroy-false-in-extjs4

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ensureAttachedToBody' of undefined` which means that `Ext.getCmp('foo');` is still null.

Comment: It does work on the latest codebase; I don't think anything related to this problem has changed between 4.2.1 and pre-4.2.3 but I'll check.

Comment: Just ran the example above against 4.2.1; works as expected. I would guesstimate that the problem is with your code.

Comment: Accepted, not sure why mine doesn't work, but at least this is a good answer.